Parallelizing highly dynamic and unbalanced loads
I have a computation with a following structure (pseudocode):
intermediate_results = []

for source in sources: # (1)
    source_data = prepare( load( source ) ) # (2)
    for sample in schedule_samples( source_data ): # (3)
        sample_data = extract_sample( source_data ) # (4)
        for result_data in postprocess_sample( sample_data ):
            intermediate_results.append( result_data )

final_results = []
for intermediate_result_group in group_intermediate_results( intermediate_results ):
    for final_result in compile_final_result( intermediate_result_group ):
        final_results.append( final_result )

The count of (1) is from 1-3 items to several thousands. The count of (3) is from hundreds to millions. And not known before actually loading data and processing it.
The (2) and (4) is very computation expensive procedures. The (2) is approximately ten times more costly than (4).
I need to parallelize the whole process in a relatively effective way.
My current implementation is based on python's multiprocessing module and parallelized only on loop (1). This is simple and working, but have an issue. Sometimes couple of sources have much more samples that others, so at the end of the process, several workers are processing such large sources, while others finished it tasks.
The relatively good solution for this process would be work sealing technique, when worker that finished it's job tries to get tasks from other workers.
Currently i need to scale this process to cluster with 10 nodes. So i thinking to use some kind of framework such as dask or ray to solve complex job scheduling.
But i've found that both of them are not very friendly to this kind of unbalanced nested dynamic workflows.
It is very simple to create dozens of independent jobs, each of that will independently load source data, but it will be very slow, so i need that tasks are able to reuse loaded data, without sacrificing ability to move work between them.
Is there any pythonic tools that could help to solve this kind of parallelization problem and how to use it correctly? Or it is better to create custom implementation?

It sounds from the question like you're not having a problem fitting this into memory, just that the loops are slow. Probably a better solution than multiprocessing (which can be quite inefficient in python) would be to try to vectorize this so you are not using loops (perform all your operations on one big table). Polars (alternative to pandas) can also be much quicker for very large data sets.
But in summary - is memory an issue for you, and have you tried eliminating the loops and using native pandas functions instead?

Do you need to process all of the data or are you searching for a specific result?

@Kraigolas, my data is not a tables. Each source is efficiently 4 dimensional numpy array with some metadata (up to 60Gb of data each). It's processing is not perfectly optimized, but relatively good: numpy itself is quite fast, couple of complex algorithms optimized via cython.
Actually, there is a memory issue on the horizon. At least on my experiments with ray, when one source happened to load several times, it quickly leads to OOM. I believe, can partially solve this issue by mmaping source data to memory, but i believe, it is not the root of the problem.

@ti7, i need to process whole dataset.

@meditativepotato I like this question, can't offer a good answer but as an aside, np.einsum is EXTREMELY powerful for high dimensional arrays. As it looks for optimal contractions, I've seen it offer 1000x less flops in my own work. I suggest investigating to see if the way you are multiplying is inoptimal.
